# How can delete listview items using checkbox?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am getting listview in my layout... I don't know how can I delete multiple items from listview when I select items in checkbox and click delete button. I am adding a piece of code.

```
public class classname extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

 ListView lv;
 ArrayList<x_obj> x_list = new ArrayList<x_obj>();
 TextView  delete;
 @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_x);
      del_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.del_txt);

del_txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           "code for delete selected items"

        }
    });
 }
public OrderAdapter(Context context, int row_layout,
            ArrayList<x_obj> items) {
        super(context, row_layout, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertview;

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
        final x obj = items.get(position);

 TextView txt_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
  CheckBox checkBox1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

  return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: so are you displaying checkboxes beside listitem? in this case,you can loop your arraylist and check whether a item is checked or not.if checked then add it to a different arraylist  and replace old arraylist with new arraylist and call notifydatasetchanged.

Comment: now i am getting checkbox in listview..i didnt do code part in checkbox..can u help..i added my code here

Comment: i am getting list items from web respons..and add that items in x object...doing that part in back ground using asynch task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class classname extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    ListView lv;
     ArrayList<x_obj> new_al=new ArrayList<x_obj>();
     ArrayList<x_obj> x_list = new ArrayList<x_obj>();
      TextView  delete;
   @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_x);
  del_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.del_txt);

   del_txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       "code for delete selected items"

    }
});
        }
          public OrderAdapter(Context context, int row_layout,
        ArrayList<x_obj> items) {
    super(context, row_layout, items);
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertview;

    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)                    
           getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
    final x obj = items.get(position);

      TextView txt_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
         CheckBox checkBox1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
             if(checkBox1.isChecked())
           {
           new_al.add(x_list.get(position));//add the element into arraylist

                }  
                 btn_clear.setOnItemClickListener(new Listener()
              {

            public void onClick(View v)
             {

             x_list.clear();
             x_list.add(new_al);
           }
            }
               );
              notifyDataSetChanged();
            return v;

              }
                  }
```

This is just an exmple.there can be syntactical errors at some places.please check them.

Comment: i think all you need to do is to add a button to clear all the checked items in the list

Comment: ia m using delete text for clear list..del_txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       "code for delete selected items"

    }
});

Answer (score 1):

try this in your adapter, i used it by extending BaseAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

final ViewHolder holder;

   if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row1, null);

        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.add_food_item);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final ItemInList element = list.get(position);

    holder.checkbox.setChecked(element.isSelected());
    holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                    if (element.isSelected()) {
                        array.add(element.getName());
                    } else {
                        if (position < array.size())
                            array.remove(position);
                    }
                }
            });

    return convertView;
}
```